# Copy clone in prefab

Tags: clone, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab with some datas (ints, strings...) and I have a Clone of this prefab. In this clone, I modify some of those ints and strings.
And after that I want to copy my Clone in the prefab, I mean that I want my prefab to have the same properties of my clone object.
I found :
`UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab`
but this is only functional in the editor.
Can you help me ? Another thing is that I don't want to copy manualy the datas.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Component Copier](http://u3d.as/content/is3d/component-copier/2BZ) is worth to look at. Although there is a little bug and the component menu is gone (right click menu in transform does the job) it helped me. And no, I am not the developer but just a user.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but for now I use an empty prefabs, and I fill it manually :(